# ORA-02291: integrity constraint (OPS$P2417335.VOD_FILM_CLASS_FK) violated - parent key not found

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, relational-database

I am having an issue with inserting values into my vod_film table. The tables are the following:

```
CREATE TABLE vod_classification (
dbClassId       CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
dbDescription       VARCHAR2(150),
CONSTRAINT vod_classification_PK PRIMARY KEY (dbClassId)
);

CREATE TABLE vod_film (
dbFilmId          NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
dbTitle           VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
dbDirector_firstname  VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
dbDirector_lastname   VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
dbGenre               VARCHAR2(20),
dbUK_release_date     DATE,
dbFilename            VARCHAR2(50),
dbRuntime         NUMBER(4),
dbClass               CHAR(3),
CONSTRAINT vod_film_PK PRIMARY KEY (dbFilmId),
CONSTRAINT vod_film_class_FK FOREIGN KEY (dbClass) REFERENCES vod_classification (dbClassId)
ON DELETE SET NULL
);

CREATE TABLE vod_actor (
dbActorId      CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
dbFirstname    VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
dbLastname     VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
dbDateOfBirth  DATE,
dbNationality  VARCHAR2(30),
dbBiography    CLOB,
CONSTRAINT vod_actor_PK PRIMARY KEY (dbActorId)
);

CREATE TABLE vod_role (
dbFilmId           NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
dbActorId          CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
dbCharacterName    VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
dbFirstAppearance  NUMBER(6),
dbDescription      CLOB,
CONSTRAINT vod_role_PK PRIMARY KEY (dbFilmId, dbActorId, dbCharacterName),
CONSTRAINT vod_role_film_FK FOREIGN KEY (dbFilmId) REFERENCES vod_film (dbFilmId)
ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT vod_role_actor_FK FOREIGN KEY (dbActorId) REFERENCES vod_actor (dbActorId)
ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

When I run the following:

```
INSERT INTO vod_film (dbFilmId, dbTitle, dbDirector_firstname, dbDirector_lastname, dbGenre, dbUK_release_date, dbFilename, dbRuntime, dbClass)
VALUES (1, 'Toy Story 3', 'lee', 'unkrich', 'Comedy', '19-JUL-2010', 'ToyStory3.mpg', 103, 'U');
```

I have this error return:

> ORA-02291: integrity constraint (OPS$P2417335.VOD_FILM_CLASS_FK) violated - parent key not found

I am unsure why this error returns because the foreign key is referenced to an existing field in the vod_classification. At the time of inserting the data the tables have all been added in what I believe to be the correct order.

Any help on why I am receiving this error would be greatly appreciated or if I need to provide any further information please tell me.

Regards,

Steven.

Comment: Most likely there is not class with ID `'U'`. See what you get when executing `SELECT * FROM vod_classification WHERE classid = 'U';`. Should be an empty set.

Comment: @stickybit I understand the error now, I am very new to SQL. I hadn't added any data to the classification table. Once I added the tuples it worked perfectly. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the message is pretty clear.  The constraint is:

```
CONSTRAINT vod_film_class_FK FOREIGN KEY (dbClass)
    REFERENCES vod_classification (dbClassId)
    ON DELETE SET NULL
```

The error is saying that you are adding a value of `dbClass` (which is '`U`').  This value is not in `vod_classification.dbClassId`.

You can check if the value is there:

```
select c.*
from vod_classification c
where c.dbClassId = 'U';
```

Comment: Thank you, what you pointed out solved my problem. I hadn't added any tuples to my classification table.